# Variance Properties - Probability

Tags: probability

I know that for expected value, if you have $E[4Y-1]$ this is equal to computing $4\times E[Y]-E[1]=4\times E[Y]-1$. Does the same properties hold for Var$(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Something similar holds, but not the exact same thing:  $$\mathrm{Var}[aX + b] = a^2 \mathrm{Var}[X] \,.$$

Comment: so using this, i have a problem i am working on which gives that Var$(Y)=7$. I want to find Var$(-5Y+7)$. Is this equal to $(-5)^2$Var$(Y+7)=(-5)^2$Var$(Y)$?

Comment: Yep, exactly, that'll do.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ and $y$ are just variables. Which conditions can be hold for $y$, those can also be hold for $x$.